# "Can't overwrite cause" when setting a cause on exception with a null cause

Tags: java, exception

I have a `RuntimeException` that has no cause (`t.getCause() returns null`). When my code runs `t.initCause(exceptionToAttach)`, it gives me an `IllegalStateException` with the message "Can't overwrite cause".

I wouldn't have thought this was possible. The exceptionToAttach is simply a new `RuntimeException()`, which seems to have itself set as the cause for some reason.

Any ideas what's going on?

**edit with some relevant code**

```
public static void addCause(Throwable e, Throwable exceptionToAttach) {
    // eff it, java won't let me do this right - causes will appear backwards sometimes (ie the rethrow will look like it came before the cause) 
    Throwable c = e;
    while(true) {
        if(c.getCause() == null) {
            break;
        }
        //else
        c = c.getCause();        // get cause here will most likely return null : ( - which means I can't do what I wanted to do
    }

    c.initCause(exceptionToAttach);
}
```

Comment: Try to isolate your problem into `SSCCE` (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example). See: http://sscce.org/

Comment: `getCause()` usually doesn't return `null`. Post the code.

Comment: I think you're wrong Ravi. I posted my code, which has been working properly for about a year and a half.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code responsible for the `IllegalStateException` exception is this:

```
public class Throwable implements Serializable {
    private Throwable cause = this;        
    public synchronized Throwable initCause(Throwable cause) {
        if (this.cause != this)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Can't overwrite cause");
        if (cause == this)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Self-causation not permitted");
        this.cause = cause;
        return this;
    }
// ..
}
```

which means that you cannot invoke constructor `public Throwable(String message, Throwable cause)` and then on the same instance invoke `initCause`.

I think your code has invoked `public Throwable(String message, Throwable cause)`, passed `null` as the `cause` and then tried to call `initCause` what is not allowed.

Comment: If you don't initialize a cause, it initializes it to itself? That explains why the new RuntimeException seems to have itself set as the cause. But it doesn't explain why my code (now posted) never goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: Ohh, you're entirely right! I created an exception class that passes null as the cause, thinking that would have the same affect as not passing a cause.